# Using SMOTE for regression

Tags: python, r, classification, regression

I am using a Random Forest regression model for my prediction task. Although my results are reasonable (in terms of RMSE), I have data points with a large RMSE due to lack of data points with similar response variables to them. Similar to classification problems with imbalanced data, I see imbalanced data in terms of my response variables (which is integer numbers). I wonder if I can define small intervals for the response variables and consider all data having response variable on that range as the same class and then use SMOTE for multi class classification to generate data for the rare classes. I tried to find a way of over sampling for regression but could not find anything useful so far. On the other hand, since SMOTE tries to generate the synthetic record based on the k nearest neighbors of a data point, I assume I need to standardize my data so the neighbors are not biased to the variables with large magnitudes. I appreciate if I can get your input about this approach.